# Running multiple python scripts in parallel from MacOS terminal screening output

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I am trying to run multiple python scripts in parallel from macos terminal via

```
python a.py &
python b.py &
python c.py &
```

Does this run the scripts concurrently in parallel, asynchronously? Or are they still run sequentially? I intend for the former, to save time. Moreover, the output from these scripts seems to overlap in the terminal window. Is there a way to screen the output from each program to a different terminal window, and maybe even write it to a separate text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. These are three separate processes that run separate from each other. Concurrency and parallelism might also depend on the number of cores in the machine and the processor os scheduler.

```
python a.py > a.out 2>&1 &
python b.py > b.out 2>&1 &
python c.py > c.out 2>&1 &
```

Comment: This works when it comes to saving files. But is it also possible to screen the output to different windows so it can be monitored?

Comment: you could tail -f the output of each of the output files in multiple windows. tail -f a.out in one window and so on

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work. tail -f is not printing anything to screen. Is it possible that this method waits for the entire script to finish running or is it concurrently writing to the *.out files?